# How can I make the Ubuntu terminal follow the same sorting with ls -l as Mac OS X uses by default?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, terminal

I like the default sorting of `ls -l` in Mac OS X and have gotten used to it. Now I'm starting to use Ubuntu machines more frequently, and I'm hoping to coerce its terminal into sorting the listing in the same way. Currently however, when I use `ls -ahlF` on Mac OS X I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 sean  staff   340B Jan 13 17:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x  16 sean  staff   544B Jan 18 17:35 ../
drwxr-xr-x  16 sean  staff   544B Jan 19 11:47 .git/
-rw-r--r--   1 sean  staff    69B Jan 13 15:34 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x   1 sean  staff   144B Jan 13 17:50 README.md*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 sean  staff   104B Jan 13 17:50 docker-compose.yml*
drwxr-xr-x   3 sean  staff   102B Jan 13 16:10 dsl/
drwxr-xr-x   6 sean  staff   204B Jan 13 17:50 jenkins/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 sean  staff   307B Jan 13 17:00 setup.sh*
drwxr-xr-x   3 sean  staff   102B Jan 13 15:52 src/
```

Whereas a `ls -ahlF` of the same git repository in the Ubuntu terminal gives me:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 sean sean 4,0K jan 19 11:18 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 sean sean 4,0K jan 19 11:17 ../
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sean sean  104 jan 19 11:18 docker-compose.yml*
drwxrwxr-x 3 sean sean 4,0K jan 19 11:18 dsl/
drwxrwxr-x 8 sean sean 4,0K jan 19 12:30 .git/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sean sean   69 jan 19 11:18 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x 2 sean sean 4,0K jan 19 11:18 jenkins/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sean sean  144 jan 19 11:18 README.md*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sean sean  307 jan 19 11:18 setup.sh*
drwxrwxr-x 3 sean sean 4,0K jan 19 11:18 src/
```

How can I achieve the desired sorting order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should sort the same way as Mac OS X by default.
What is your `locale`?

You can change `LC_ALL` by typing:

`export LC_ALL="C"`

If you don't want to change `locale` in your system you can make an alias and add it to `.bashrc`

`alias ll='LC_COLLATE=C ls -ahlF'`

To use it, simply type `ll` in terminal which will execute `ls -ahlF` command with locale give.

Comment: After trying a bucket of options and cleaning up a bunch more, I finally managed to fix it by unsetting all LC_ related environment variables and subsequently setting `LC_COLLATE=C` again. Much obliged.